# Store Data in Array, Hide Some Rows, and Write Data Back to Non-Hidden Rows

Tags: excel, vba

In the worksheet called "EIRP LL", Range L6:O13 contains data. Sometimes, rows 7-13 get hidden for reasons unrelated to this data. The data in Range L6:O13 shall remain unhidden, so the data in L6:O13 is copied into an array called ConfigDataArray. Range L6:O13 is then cleared. All of this code works.

Then, the difficulty begins. The data that is stored in ConfigDataArray must be written to the non-hidden rows beginning with Row 6, which happens to always be unhidden. I have attempted to do this by slicing the rows of the array and iterating through these rows with a For loop. But it doesn't work. Only the 1st and 3rd rows of the array data get written back into the worksheet, and the third row gets written into a hidden row. The code beginning with j = 6 and ending with Next, clearly is faulty. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
Sub HideLLRows()
'Hide blank rows in EIRP LL
'Where blank row is defined as no data in Col B for the given row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ConfigDataArray As Variant
Set EIRPLL = Sheets("EIRP LL")
LastLLRow = EIRPLL.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'Put the metadata into an 8Row x 4Col array for safe keeping
ConfigDataArray = Range("L6:O13").Value

'Clear the metadata cells
Range("L6:O13").Clear

'Hide the blank rows
For i = 6 To LastLLRow
    If EIRPLL.Range("B" & i) = "" Then
        EIRPLL.Rows(i).Hidden = Not EIRPLL.Rows(i).Hidden
    End If
Next

'Slice the 8 array rows and put into the first 8 non-hidden rows
'beginning on L6:O6 (which is always non-hidden)

j = 6
For k = 1 To 8
    If Rows(j).Hidden = False Then
        If k < 9 Then
            EIRPLL.Range("L" & k + 5) = Application.Index(ConfigDataArray, k, 1)
            EIRPLL.Range("M" & k + 5) = Application.Index(ConfigDataArray, k, 2)
            EIRPLL.Range("N" & k + 5) = Application.Index(ConfigDataArray, k, 3)
            EIRPLL.Range("O" & k + 5) = Application.Index(ConfigDataArray, k, 4)
        End If
    End If
    k = k + 1
    j = j + 1
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: These two parts of your description seem to be in conflict: "Sometimes, rows 6-13 get hidden for reasons unrelated to this data" and "must be written to the non-hidden rows beginning with Row 6, which happens to always be unhidden"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub HideLLRows()

Dim ConfigDataArray As Variant, i, k, j
Dim EIRPLL As Worksheet, LastLLRow

    Set EIRPLL = Sheets("EIRP LL")

    LastLLRow = EIRPLL.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Clear the metadata cells
    With EIRPLL.Range("L6:O13")
        ConfigDataArray = .Value
        .Clear
    End With

    'Hide the blank rows
    For i = 6 To LastLLRow
        If EIRPLL.Range("B" & i) = "" Then
            EIRPLL.Rows(i).Hidden = True
        End If
    Next

    k = 1
    j = 6
    Do While k <= 8
        With EIRPLL.Rows(j)
            If Not .Hidden Then
                .Cells(12).Value = ConfigDataArray(k, 1)
                .Cells(13).Value = ConfigDataArray(k, 2)
                .Cells(14).Value = ConfigDataArray(k, 3)
                .Cells(15).Value = ConfigDataArray(k, 4)
                k = k + 1
            End If
        End With
        j = j + 1
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes! Your Do While solves the problem. Sorry for my delay in responding. This is my first dabble into arrays, and this helps quite a bit. Much thanks.